# In immersive mode how can I limit the display of the system and nav bars

Tags: java, android, user-interface, cocos2d-x, android-immersive

I am currently using the **IMMERSIVE_STICKY** flag in an Android game I am creating using **cocos2d-x** by implementing it in my **AppActivity.java** file.

However the default behavior is to show the system and navigation bars in portrait mode when the user swipes downward from the top of the screen **AND** when the user swipes upward from the bottom of the screen.

I would like to:

1. incorporate upward swipes from the bottom of the screen as a game play element **BUT** this triggers the display of the navigation bar
2. I would like to limit the display of these bars so they are **ONLY** displayed when the user swipes from the **TOP**. This way my game can take advantage of the added screen real estate and accept user input at the bottom of the screen as well.

Can anybody please tell me how to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any examples of apps that do this?  I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: I don't know, hopefully someone can give me some hackish way to do it. But it would make sense, why doesn't google allow for it and give instruction on how to do it? It could add an extra game play element to games that could benefit from it. Users and developers would only have to worry about one side of the screen interfering with game play. Right now this behavior is limiting me in what I can do with my game.